# Converting a list of named list to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list returned by `sapply` which looks like this:

```
> my_list
        [,1]    [,2]    [,3]     [,4]    
val     1.73    2.73    4.71     5.27     
cost    10.1    8.71    9.95     0.01
time    5.36    5.84    5.68     2.10
```

I'd like to convert it into a data frame:

| id | val | cost | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.73 | 10.1 | 5.36 |
| 2 | 2.73 | 8.71 | 5.84 |
| 3 | 4.71 | 9.95 | 5.68 |
| 4 | 5.27 | 0.01 | 2.10 |

How can I transform the list into the data frame this way?

Edit: Here is the output of `dput(my_list)`:

```
structure(list(1.73, 10.1, 5.36,2.73,8.71,5.84, 
  4.71,9.95,5.68, 5.27, 0.01, 2.10), 
  dim = c(3L, 4L), dimnames = list(c("val", 
  "cost", "time"), NULL))
```

Comment: Please share `dput(my_list)` to make it clear what the structure of the data is.

Comment: This looks like a matrix rather than a list. Perhaps `cbind(id = seq(ncol(my_list)), as.data.frame(t(my_list)))` will give the desired output?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yours works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `t`

```r
t(dat) |>
  transform(id = seq(ncol(dat)))
```

```r
   val cost time id
1 1.73 10.1 5.36  1
2 2.73 8.71 5.84  2
3 4.71 9.95 5.68  3
4 5.27 0.01  2.1  4
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the data are `list` elements, if we want to make it regular vectors, an option is `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
t(my_list) %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  unnest(where(is.list)) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(), .before = 1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     id   val  cost  time
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  1.73 10.1   5.36
2     2  2.73  8.71  5.84
3     3  4.71  9.95  5.68
4     4  5.27  0.01  2.1
```